# Problems with installing postgresql extensions inside docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have docker file

```
FROM postgres:10.10

ARG PATHMAN_VERSION=1.5.8
ARG PG_DEV_VERSION=10

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget unzip make postgresql-server-dev-$PG_DEV_VERSION gcc libc6-dev libssl-dev libkrb5-dev \
    && wget -O /tmp/pg_pathman.zip https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_pathman/archive/$PATHMAN_VERSION.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/pg_pathman.zip  -d /tmp \
    && cd /tmp/pg_pathman-$PATHMAN_VERSION \
    && make USE_PGXS=1 install \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ca-certificates wget unzip make postgresql-server-dev-$PG_DEV_VERSION gcc libc6-dev libssl-dev libkrb5-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pg_*
```

I want to install pg_pathman extension, but got

```
+ make USE_PGXS=1 install
Makefile:83: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```